# Trouble installing packages in the wrong Python version

Tags: python, package

I'm having problems while installing a new package in Python. I was looking for the **termcolor** package. I installed it using the apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python-termcolor
```

But when I try to use it in Python 3.6 it keep telling me that's not installed. I checked whether it was and I got:

```
cris@Manaos:~$ dpkg -L python-termcolor
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/pyshared
/usr/share/pyshared/termcolor-1.1.0.egg-info
/usr/share/pyshared/termcolor.py
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-termcolor
/usr/share/doc/python-termcolor/README.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-termcolor/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-termcolor/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-termcolor/CHANGES.rst
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/termcolor-1.1.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/termcolor.py
```

So I understand that the package was correctly installed, but in the v2.7. How do I get it installed in the v3.6?

**EDIT:** I've read that if a use the pip installer, I could assign in which version of Python I'd like it installed, like using pip3 to install the package in 3.XX. But I tried it, it says that it was correctly installed and when I open Python 3.6 and try to use it, still got the ModuleNotFoundError.

**EDIT2:** After checking one more time, I discovered that with pip3 I installed the termcolor package in Python 3.5.3, but how can I get it installed in Python 3.6.1?

Comment: You should instead install package `python3-termcolor` . This will correctly install for your required python version. I would normally recommend to use pip3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify you want the python 3 version.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-termcolor
```